# code reuse in front-end rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, web, user-controls

I'm in the process of development a new website and I noticed the fact that couple of controls appears in different pages. So, a naive approach would be writing those controls every single time, but I'm sure there must be a better way. ASP.NET offers `UserControl`.

What is the best practice for rails environment?

Comment: Take a look at `yield` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)

Comment: great. You might want to write it as an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `yield` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield), as well as `partials` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

This guide should be able to help you anyway: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html